# Regression problem optimization using ML or DL

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization, deep-learning, neural-network

I have some data (data from sensors and etc.) from an energy system. consider the x-axis is temperature and the y-axis is energy consumption. **Suppose we just have data and we don't have access to the mathematical formulation of the problem**:

[energy consumption vs temperature curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4sSV.jpg)

In the above figure, it is absolutely obvious that the **optimum point is 20**. **I want to predict the optimum point using ML or DL models**. Based on the courses that I have taken I know that it's a regression supervised learning problem, however, I don't know how can I do optimization on this kind of problem.

I don't want you to write a code for this problem. I just want you to give me some hints and instructions about doing this optimization problem.

Also if you recommend any references or courses, I will welcome them to learn how to predict the optimum point of a regression supervised learning problem without knowing the mathematical formulation of the problem.

Comment: Your question is quite not clear. Because you already have the whole data, you can find the global minimum from your data. If you only have a physical or mathematical model instead of data, you can find local minima using optimization methods such as [gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) ones.

Comment: You're right, in real conditions, there are several input variables (temperatures, pressures, etc.) that increase the complexity (even the visualization of such an amount of data wouldn't be possible), also in real conditions, sometimes the optimum operating point has not been captured using experimental tests, so we have to predict the optimum point based on the previous data.

Comment: @J.Choi I've edited the figure, It might be more understandable

Comment: It seems like you want to create a data-driven multivariate (multivariable) model and find its global minimum. The existence of minima is determined by the type of a model that you defined. For example, a convex model has its global minimum and can be easily optimized. General models (including neural network ones) may have multiple saddle points. Linear models without bounds do not have minima. If you properly defined your model structure and finished its learning process, you can easily find local minima by using heatmap-like visualizations.

Comment: @J.Choi Can you please explain more? or introduce a reference or course if you know?

Comment: How Siemens use ML with optimization in optimizing wind turbines locations: https://blogs.nvidia.com/blog/2022/03/22/siemens-gamesa-wind-farms-digital-twins/  I know it's far more complex and I don't want this level of complexity by the concept is kind of the same

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways that you can try when it comes to optimizing your model, for example, fine tuning your model. What you can do with fine tuning is to try different options that a model consists of and find the smallest errors or higher accuracy based on the actual and predicted data.

Using [DecisionTreeRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor) model, you can try to use different split criterion, limit the minimum number of split & depth to see which give you the best predicted scores/errors. For neural network model, using [keras](https://keras.io/api/#optimizers), you can try different optimizers, try different loss functions, tune your parameters etc. and try all out as a combination of model.

As for resources, you can go Google, Youtube, and other platform to use keywords such as "fine tuning DNN model" and a lot of resources will pop up for your reference. The bottom line is that you will need to try out different models and fine tune your model until when you are satisfied with your results. The results will be based on your judgement and there is no right or wrong answers (i.e., errors are always there), it just completely up to you on how would you like to achieve your solution with handful of ML and DL models that you got. My advice to you is to spend more time on getting your hands dirty. It will be worth it in the long run. HFGL!